# SQL automatic data conversion from DEC to HEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have not much in common with SQL databases.

[image: Photo of Database]

I need to convert Serial number to HEX, Dk number to HEX and connect these numbers.  After some research I made this code

```
update dbo.UsersAccessUnit
  set Code = convert(nvarchar(3), Convert(varbinary(1), 255), 2 ) + convert(nvarchar(5), Convert(varbinary(2), 65534 ), 2 ) 
   where Id between '1' and '2000';
```

And it works fine. But I want to do all rows automatically. How could I do that?

If I write like this:

```
update dbo.UsersAccessUnit
      set Code = convert(nvarchar(3), Convert(varbinary(1), Serial), 2 ) + convert(nvarchar(5), Convert(varbinary(2), Dk), 2 ) 
       where Id between '1' and '2000';
```

It doesn't get the right answer.

Comment: mysql or sql server? they are not same?

Comment: also, I don't clearly understand your problem. Why dont u just remove where clause?

Comment: sorry. sql server.

with my code i am editing just one single line and I want to edit all rows at once.

Comment: please try without where clause?

Comment: So why isn't the comment from @ErayBalkanli the answer..? Are we missing a vital piece of information?

Comment: But how do I take value of row 1, convert it to HEX, save it to specific cell, and later take value from row 2, convert it to HEX and go on?

Comment: The reason you don't get the right answer from the other is because the varbinary representation of `255` is different to `'255'`, and again to `N'255'`. Why do you want to store a `varbinary` as a `varchar` anyway? Why not leave it as the correct datatype?

Comment: if i use `varchar` i don't get the HEX value. I want automatic proccess through all rows: Take SERIAL column data convert it to Hex value connect it with DK column HEX data and store it in CODE column

Comment: I think you need to be more clear here. You still haven't explained why just removing the `WHERE` would work, as that would update **every** row in the table. Perhaps you want a persisted computed column?

Comment: If i remove `WHERE` all column in database will be the same number. the problem is not about cause `WHERE`. The problem is that i need every row converted to HEX depending on that row values.

Comment: Where do you get that idea? The `SET` operation is a row level expression, if all the rows have different value, running an expression based on the value of that column will return a different value. Just like in a `SELECT`. For example `UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = [Column] + 1;` would increase the value of every row by 1, not change every value to a (random} single row's value + 1.